I am trying to install the necessary packages on miniconda, by using the command: "(base) $ conda create -y -n pydata-book python=3.10"
(base) $ conda create -y -n pydata-book python=3.10 

this gives me a message: "-y" is not recognized as an intern or extern command by executables lotes
is it a problem or it doesn't matter? if so how can I solve it?
I hope it will just work without any message

That command looks fine to me, though I'm not a conda expert. Are you sure that's exactly how you typed it in? Also, that error message doesn't sound right (I've never even heard the word "lotes" before); did you translate it from Spanish? Please post the original error in addition to the translation.

For reference, conda create --help says "-y, --yes Sets any confirmation values to 'yes' automatically. Users will not be asked to confirm any adding, deleting, backups, etc."

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. You can [edit].

Is the actual error "... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?

thanks @wjandrea I have solved by deleting the "-y", by using the following command only:  conda create -n pydata-book python=3.10 #according to the python version

For future questions, please copy and paste whatever error message you get and format it like code.

just delete the "-y", as follows:
conda create -n pydata-book python=3.10 #use the version of python here instead

